# How to loop through similar to a for loop

Tags: t-sql

I have checked the forum here and understand that t-SQL does not have FOR loops. However, I'm wondering the best way to do what I need to do here.

Here is my table (mytable) simplified:

```
id  Code1  Code2  Code3  CodeDesc1  CodeDesc2  CodeDesk3
__  _____  _____  _____  _________  _________  _________
1   ABC    DEF    ZYX
2   DEF    ABC    ZYX
3   ZYX    GHJ    ABC
```

There are many more rows and many more Code and CodeDesc columns in the real situation. I am converting SAS code to T-SQL and the SAS code has this (simplified):

```
DO  x = 1 to 4 ;
 IF code0(x) = 'ABC' THEN CodeDesc0(x) = 'ABC Description'
ELSE 
 IF code0(x) = 'DEF' THEN CodeDesc0(x) = 'DEF Description'
ELSE
 IF code0(x) = 'ZYX' THEN CodeDesc0(x) = 'ZYX Description'
```

My question is how can I do something similar in T-SQL.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Adding more info...

If I were to do what I need to do using straight T-SQL, without any programming it would look like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET CodeDesc1 = 'ABC Description' WHERE Code1 = 'ABC'
UPDATE mytable SET CodeDesc2 = 'ABC Description' WHERE Code2 = 'ABC'
UPDATE mytable SET CodeDesc3 = 'ABC Description' WHERE Code3 = 'ABC'
UPDATE mytable SET CodeDesc1 = 'DEF Description' WHERE Code1 = 'DEF'
UPDATE mytable SET CodeDesc2 = 'DEF Description' WHERE Code2 = 'DEF'
UPDATE mytable SET CodeDesc3 = 'DEF Description' WHERE Code3 = 'DEF'
```

So, as you can see with several different codes and descriptions I could easily be writing 100's of update statements to cover all the possibilities.

I hope that helps to shed a bit more light.

Comment: Are you attempting to do the same thing for every item in the loop?

Comment: Is it possible to change this table structure? If you normalize the data (a table associating `Id` and `Code`, and another associating `Code` with `CodeDesc`), the updates as you describe them shouldn't be needed at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a loop. Upddates should never be done in loops!!!!

What I would do is create a table that maps the abreviations to the long descriptions.
Then you can add new ones easily and you can write the update this way:

```
Update a
set description = b.description
from tableA a 
join tableb b on a.abbreviation = b.abbrevation
where a.description <> b.descrioption or a.description is null
```

Comment: Awesome. Much better than looping. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what you're looking for:

```
/********** example 1 **********/ 

declare @au_id char( 11 )

set rowcount 0
select * into #mytemp from authors

set rowcount 1

select @au_id = au_id from #mytemp

while @@rowcount <> 0
begin
    set rowcount 0
    select * from #mytemp where au_id = @au_id
    delete #mytemp where au_id = @au_id

    set rowcount 1
    select @au_id = au_id from #mytemp<BR/>
end
set rowcount 0
```

Taken from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111401

Comment: Thank you. I saw this too but honestly could not figure out how to make it work for my situation. I have updated my original post to perhaps shed a bit more light.